# Importing csv file using COPY FROM on Mac

Tags: postgresql, filepath, pgadmin-4, import-csv

Using the query editor in the pgAdmin4 app, I would like to import data from a csv file into a table. My code is as follows:

```
CREATE DATABASE gps_tracking_db
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    TEMPLATE = template0
    LC_COLLATE = 'C'
    LC_CTYPE = 'C';
    
CREATE SCHEMA main;

COMMENT ON SCHEMA main IS 'Schema that stores all the GPS tracking core data.';

CREATE TABLE main.gps_data(
    gps_data_id serial,
    gps_sensors_code character varying,
    line_no integer,
    utc_date date,
    utc_time time without time zone,
    lmt_date date,
    lmt_time time without time zone,
    ecef_x integer,
    ecef_y integer,
    ecef_z integer,
    latitude double precision,
    longitude double precision,
    height double precision,
    dop double precision,
    nav character varying(2),
    validated character varying(3),
    sats_used integer,
    ch01_sat_id integer,
    ch01_sat_cnr integer,
    ch02_sat_id integer,
    ch02_sat_cnr integer,
    ch03_sat_id integer,
    ch03_sat_cnr integer,
    ch04_sat_id integer,
    ch04_sat_cnr integer,
    ch05_sat_id integer,
    ch05_sat_cnr integer,
    ch06_sat_id integer,
    ch06_sat_cnr integer,
    ch07_sat_id integer,
    ch07_sat_cnr integer,
    ch08_sat_id integer,
    ch08_sat_cnr integer,
    ch09_sat_id integer,
    ch09_sat_cnr integer,
    ch10_sat_id integer,
    ch10_sat_cnr integer,
    ch11_sat_id integer,
    ch11_sat_cnr integer,
    ch12_sat_id integer,
    ch12_sat_cnr integer,
    main_vol double precision,
    bu_vol double precision,
    temp double precision,
    easting integer,
    northing integer,
    remarks character varying
);

COMMENT ON TABLE main.gps_data
IS 'Table that stores raw data as they come from the sensors (plus the ID of
the sensor).';

ALTER TABLE main.gps_data
    ADD CONSTRAINT gps_data_pkey
    PRIMARY KEY(gps_data_id);

ALTER TABLE main.gps_data
    ADD COLUMN insert_timestamp timestamp with time zone
    DEFAULT now();
    
ALTER TABLE main.gps_data
    ADD CONSTRAINT unique_gps_data_record
    UNIQUE(gps_sensors_code, line_no); /*what does line_no mean?*/
    
COPY main.gps_data(
    gps_sensors_code, line_no, utc_date, utc_time, lmt_date, lmt_time, ecef_x,
    ecef_y, ecef_z, latitude, longitude, height, dop, nav, validated, sats_used,
    ch01_sat_id, ch01_sat_cnr, ch02_sat_id, ch02_sat_cnr, ch03_sat_id,
    ch03_sat_cnr, ch04_sat_id, ch04_sat_cnr, ch05_sat_id, ch05_sat_cnr,
    ch06_sat_id, ch06_sat_cnr, ch07_sat_id, ch07_sat_cnr, ch08_sat_id,
    ch08_sat_cnr, ch09_sat_id, ch09_sat_cnr, ch10_sat_id, ch10_sat_cnr,
    ch11_sat_id, ch11_sat_cnr, ch12_sat_id, ch12_sat_cnr, main_vol, bu_vol,
    temp, easting, northing, remarks)
FROM
    '/Users/CDDEP/Downloads⁩/Urbano 2014/⁩tracking_db⁩/data⁩/sensors_data⁩/GSM01438.csv'
    WITH (FORMAT csv, HEADER, DELIMITER ';')
```

However, when I run the CREATE FROM command, the following error message is returned:

> ERROR:  could not open file "/Users/CDDEP/Downloads⁩/Urbano 2014/⁩tracking_db⁩/data⁩/sensors_data⁩/GSM01438.csv" for reading: No such file or directory
> HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
> SQL state: 58P01

I wonder if the error is due to a formatting issue with the Mac filepath or something else.

Comment: Did you follow the hint? Does `/Users/CDDEP/Downloads⁩/Urbano 2014/⁩tracking_db⁩/data⁩/sensors_data⁩/GSM01438.csv` exist on the machine the **server** runs on? Is it readable for the server process?

Comment: Options 1) Do everything up to the `COPY` command in the query editor and then use [Import/Export](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/6.2/import_export_data.html) to import the data. 2) Use `psql` to run the script and `\copy` instead of `COPY`.

Comment: Thank you! I will give that a try as soon as I’m able and report back. I tried importing the csv in R with the same file path and did not have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the file `/Users/CDDEP/Downloads⁩/Urbano 2014/⁩tracking_db⁩/data⁩/sensors_data⁩/GSM01438.csv` does exists
2. Replace `COPY main.gps_data` with `\COPY main.gps_data` to use the client side utility

Comment: This is not going to work, `\copy` is a `psql` command and will not work in the `pgAdmin4` query editor.